# Retina display: 1px border vs box-shadow as border - unsharp on retina, does not show up on regular display

Tags: border, retina-display, css

Because of retina displays have such a high pixel density, 1 pixel borders can look pretty big on these displays. As suggested by Brad Birdsall, the CSS `box-shadow` property can be used to create "0,5 px" borders that look much more elegant on retina display (see http://bradbirdsall.com/mobile-web-in-high-resolution).

In one of his examples, he does this:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #000,
            inset 0 1px 0 #75c2f8,
            0 1px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
```

where `inset 0 0 1px #000` basically equals that "0,5px" border - it looks great on my iPhone. But when zooming in, you can clearly see that the line is *not* sharp - it has some kind of blur on one side which is caused because it's a box shadow and no border I believe. Is there anything I can do about it?

Also, on my non-retina Laptop display, nothing shows up. Is that normal because the line is just to thin or am I doing something wrong? I am just using his example syntax like this:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #000;
```

Comment: Because of their high pixel density shouldn't borders look smaller on Retina? 1 pixel is always 1 pixel. Maybe you see the border that big because you're not working with native DPI...

Comment: I know this is a bit of a "bump" but just to clarify to others reading this, on a MacBook Pro with retina display, 1px is not 1px since the computer SIMULATES a 1440x900 screen and does actually use more than 1px to represent a "1px solid border".

@Sven did you ever get this working? I tried but gave up as I ended up with only a shadow at the bottom. I think Brad Birdsall missed a little bit of the explanation out.

Comment: @dieselpower44 No, I never got it working and stopped using the spread radius since then when user zoom is activated. Such a shame!

Answer (score 0):

I found that setting the box-shadow spread to a value equal to `1 / window.devicePixelRatio` fixed the issue. It looks good on regular screens (dpr = 1), and retina / high res displays which have a range of values for dpr, on my screen specifically it's 1.25 (so the spread is 0.8).